# Processing radio buttons in php

Tags: php, mysqli, radio-button

I have a form which involves a number of inserts, including a number of radio button pairs, which for some reason when selected are showing no changes in the database.  I am using the same method for the radio buttons as I would use for any other input.

HTML form

```
 <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="apartmentID" value="<?php get_text_byID("SELECT apartmentID from apartment_details WHERE apartmentID=?", "apartmentID"); ?>"/>
                <input id="name"  name="name" value="<?php get_text_byID("SELECT name from apartment_details WHERE apartmentID=?", "name"); ?>"/>                   <div id="amenities">
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Y</th>
                        <th>N</th>
                        <th>Amenity</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="wifi"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="wifi"/></td>
                        <td>Wifi</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="phone"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="phone"/></td>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="TV"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="TV"/></td>
                        <td>Television</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="washing_machine"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="washing_machine"/></td>
                        <td>Washing machine</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="1" name="ac"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="0" name="ac"/></td>
                        <td>Air Conditioner</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>                     
           </div>
           <button type="submit" name="apartment_details">Save Details</button>   
            </form>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['apartment_details'])) {
include 'connect.php';
$apartmentID = (isset($_POST['apartmentID']) ? $_POST['apartmentID'] : null);
$name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
$wifi = (isset($_POST['wifi']) ? $_POST['wifi'] : null);
$phone = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : null);
$TV = (isset($_POST['TV']) ? $_POST['TV'] : null);
$washing_machine = (isset($_POST['washing_machine']) ? $_POST['washing_machine'] : null);
$ac = (isset($_POST['ac']) ? $_POST['ac'] : null);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO apartment_details (apartmentID, name,  wifi, phone, TV, washing_machine, ac) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE apartmentID = VALUES(apartmentID), name= VALUES(name),  wifi = VALUES(wifi), phone = VALUES(phone), TV = VALUES(TV), washing_machine = VALUES(washing_machine), ac = VALUES(ac)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $apartmentID, $name, $wifi, $phone, $TV, $washing_machine, $ac);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that your `if` block is running at all? Insert an `echo "hi there!";` at the very beginning of the block.

Comment: The if block is working, the radio buttons are not.  As I have tested to code without the radio buttons and it worked fine.

Comment: I think you are confusing radio buttons with checkboxes. The way radio buttons are always either on or off, so `isset()`will always bring a boolean true.  check instead for their value as to whether they are either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You radio buttons are set as either value 0 or 1;  they are not the same thing as check boxes.   Try this instead  (edited to set values:

```
if ($_POST['wifi'] == 0) {
   $wifi = 0;
}
else {
   $wifi = 1;
}
```

Note:  you can set them as a default selected value in your form, or just pull the value from the database and have that as the selected value in the form.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by do one thing?

Comment: okay, changed to make it clearer.  If you like, you can do it the way you were before with your original ternary expression, just add the if statement

Comment: Don't use null for 0;  just use 0 or 1.  You can set the datatype in the database as TINYINT if you like

Comment: Tried this however I'm getting an error stating unexpected if

Comment: Tried that however I'm getting error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: sorry about that.  typo.  fixed